# How to return WideString from COM server?

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2006, widestring

This Interface at _TLB.pas file

```
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: ITMyCOM
// Flags: (256) OleAutomation
// GUID: {D94769D0-F4AF-41E9-9111-4D8BC2F42D69}
// *********************************************************************//
ITMyCOM = interface(IUnknown)
['{D94769D0-F4AF-41E9-9111-4D8BC2F42D69}']
function MyDrawWS(a: Integer; b: Integer): WideString; stdcall;
end;
```

This looks at OS Windows

```
[
odl,
uuid(D94769D0-F4AF-41E9-9111-4D8BC2F42D69),
version(1.0),
helpstring("Interface for TMyCOM Object"),
oleautomation
]
interface ITMyCOM : IUnknown {
BSTR _stdcall MyDrawWS(
[in] long a, 
[in] long b);
};
```

Function in COM server looks as

```
function TTMyCOM.MyDrawWS(a, b: Integer): WideString;
begin
Result := WideString(IntToStr(a+b));
end;
```

In COM Client i`m calling this function like

```
Edit1.Text := String(MyCOM.MyDrawWS(1,1));
```

and get error **First chance exception at $75A9FBAE. Exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 75A409A4 in module 'RPCRT4.dll'. Read of address FFFFFFF8'. Process Project1.exe (2296)**

If i want returning Integer, it`s works. How to return WideString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to handle this is as follows:

```
[ 
odl, 
uuid(D94769D0-F4AF-41E9-9111-4D8BC2F42D69), 
version(1.0), 
helpstring("Interface for TMyCOM Object"), 
oleautomation 
] 
interface ITMyCOM : IUnknown { 
HRESULT _stdcall MyDrawWS( 
[in] long a,  
[in] long b,
[out, retval] BSTR* ret); 
}; 

ITMyCOM = interface(IUnknown) 
  ['{D94769D0-F4AF-41E9-9111-4D8BC2F42D69}'] 
  function MyDrawWS(a: Integer; b: Integer; out ret: WideString): HResult; stdcall; 
end; 

function TTMyCOM.MyDrawWS(a, b: Integer; out ret: WideString): HRESULT; 
begin 
  ret := IntToStr(a+b);
  Result := S_OK;
end; 

var
  W: WideString;
begin
  OleCheck(MyCOM.MyDrawWS(1, 1, W));
  Edit1.Text := W;
end;
```

Which can then be simplified a little by using Delphi's `safecall` calling convention in the Delphi declaration (not in the TypeLibrary itself) of the interface:

```
ITMyCOM = interface(IUnknown) 
  ['{D94769D0-F4AF-41E9-9111-4D8BC2F42D69}'] 
  function MyDrawWS(a: Integer; b: Integer): WideString; safecall;
end; 

function TTMyCOM.MyDrawWS(a, b: Integer): WideString;
begin 
  Result := IntToStr(a+b);
end; 

Edit1.Text := MyCOM.MyDrawWS(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let Delphi perform the conversions automatically. Don't cast. You can cast a (ansi)string to a PChar, because their memory layout are compatible, but you can't cast a string to a widestring or viceversa. Delphi will perfrom conversion when you assign one to the other.

In Delphi < 2009

```
var
S: string;
W: WideString;
...
S := W;  // Conversion, WideString -> AnsiString;
W := S; // Conversion, AnsiString -> WideString
```

Comment: Applied to your code, a plain `Result:=IntToStr(a+b);` will do

Comment: Another solution is to use MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() directly using the correct codepages, but unless their flexibility is needed is better to let Delphi call the appropriate conversion functions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use return values other than HRESULT. Instead put your return value into parameter list as output parameter.

```
function MyDrawWS(a: Integer; b: Integer; out str : WideString): HRESULT; stdcall;
```

In this way, you are also forced to use COM memory manager IMalloc (CoTaskMemAlloc for pur COM, SysAllocString for Automation).

Comment: Not true. When you declare an **out reval** parameter in the type library editor, Delphi will generate a function, using the **safecall** convention. It's the safecall that takes care of the HRESULT value and generate an exception if not S_OK, while letting you to use the call as a plain function.

Comment: But this is not about safecall, so we should follow COM rules here.

Comment: `safecall` is Delphi's wrapper around COM functions.  If a COM function is declared in the TypeLibrary as returning an HRESULT return value and having a 'retval' parameter, `safecall` can safely be used with it. The `safecall` function return value needs to be the same data type as the 'retval' parameter data type, and the 'retval' parameter itself should NOT be declared in the `safecall` function.  When called in the app's code, `safecall` will allocate a temp variable, call the COM function with the variable in the 'retval' parameter, do HRESULT checking, and return the variable's value.

Comment: Okay, but safecall is not used here hence the HRESULT, stdcall and out parameter. If anybody doesn't use safecall then HRESULT should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`SysAllocString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx) or [`SysAllocStringLen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221639.aspx) to allocate the BSTR.

Comment: Or you can just use `WideString` and let the RTL do all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

First chance exception at $75A9FBAE. Exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 75A409A4 in module 'RPCRT4.dll'

1. the error is coming from RPCRT4.dll
2. EAccessViolation is mostly caused by accessing a null object, step through your code make sure all objects are valid objects.